# Need alternative for $SchemaQualifiedObjectName$

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2015

I'm editing the file which helps Visual Studio create a stored procedure, and this includes the parameter `$SchemaQualifiedObjectName$`.  When VS creates the Sproc, this parameter is replaced by the stored procedure name with square brackets and a dbo tacked on to the beginning, like this:

> [dbo].[stored_proc_name]

This works great for the part of the script that looks like "CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stored_proc_name]", but for the part where I conditionally drop the procedure before creating it:

```
IF EXISTS (select * from sys.procedures where name = '$SchemaQualifiedObjectName$')
    BEGIN
        DROP  Procedure  $SchemaQualifiedObjectName$
    END
GO
```

...it produces text like this:

```
select * from sys.procedures where name = '[dbo].[stored_proc_name]'
```

which doesn't find anything because the name field does not contain square brackets or the owner name (dbo)!

The question is, is there a replaceable parameter that I could use in place of `$SchemaQualifiedObjectName$` that would yield only `stored_proc_name`?

Comment: What about using `object_id`?

Comment: as in `where object_id = object_id('$SchemaQualifiedObjectName$')`

Comment: Well, @shawnt00, what about putting that as the answer?  It works!  :-)  By the way, I really like your colorful avatar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object_id()` can handle the full name:

```
where object_id = object_id('$SchemaQualifiedObjectName$')
```

Comment: Works great!  Thanks!

Comment: @Cyberherbalist Thanks for the nice little rep bonus. Glad it helped.